# image is not loading even though src attribute is entered correctly with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, src

I made an img tag and entered the src with jquery, the source is loaded correctly when I look up the source code in the browser but the img does not load anyone knows why?

I used this method

img tag with id "icon"

$("#icon").attr("src","http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/partly-cloudy-day-xxl.png");

when I test it like this it doesnt load either

img id="icon" alt="please load" src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/partly-cloudy-day-xxl.png"

Comment: for what it's worth I got a 403 on that url

Comment: probably the access is restricted to its own HTTP_REFERER

Comment: n-dru i'm not sure what that means

Comment: i've got the feeling it's more than that

Comment: @miklovelka Basically, they mean **we can't open the link!!!**

Comment: the owner/admin of that site doesn't want you to source his images so in .htaccess file he placed special formula which prevents files with png extension from being accessed from beyond its own domain

Comment: I have no issues opening the link

Comment: In this case, I think you would be better to download the image to your machine and pull it in from your file system.

Comment: I have no idea why he wouldn't want people to use the icons since it's from a free icondb website

Comment: Probably they just don't want to act like a Content Delivery Network.

Comment: it's funnt because the black icons work perfectly only the white ones don't load

Comment: I managed to get the src, no problem. The white background is just its css! Check it in firebug on their site.

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes gives an NetworkError 403 and sometimes not. There is a plenty of reasons why that can happen - you can read it for example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403
Also read iconsdb.com term of use point 5 - they don't guarantee constant accessibility, so you better store that image locally. Probably they just don't want you to use their bandwith.